# SQL query for calculating arrival time of bus based on departure time, time from origin and stop order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this little task in which I need to calculate the arrival time for a bus based on few conditions. First, the format of departure time is like this: 1530 which means 15:30 or 3:30PM, there is other example using 830 which means 8:30AM.

Now, other column in the db table holds the time from origin in which the bus will reach the destination. For example, there might be departure time of 830 and time from origin will be 115, which means it will reach the next destination in 1 hour and 15 minutes or 945 (9:45AM).

The last property on which we need to build the arrival time is the stop order. For example, there might be 8 stations on the way from point A to point B and we need to calculate the arrival time beginning from the 2nd point onwards. Now, if the stop order is again 1 we need to reset the arrival time and start over again, it means that the row is for another destination.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to build some query which might do this thing, I can do the operation in C# but if there is any option for the arrival time to be populated in SQL, I'll be grateful for every advice.

Lastly, you can check a screenshot of the actual database I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post for us what queries you've tried?

Comment: This can definitely be done in SQL but it is going to be an incredible pain with the way your data is currently laid out. I would recommend formatting these integer fields as date fields so you can utilize SQL Servers built in time functions. Otherwise you are going to have to add in a mountain of logic to handle the fact that 830 really means 8.50 for subtraction purposes.

Comment: @jbarker2160 no queries yet, I'm thinking loudly, because I'm not sure if SQL can do what I need exactly. Thanks for any help

Comment: How can you tell the buses apart? Your data sample as shown has duplicate rows for `DepartureTime=1530, StopOrder=1, TimeFromOrigin=0` as well as `StopOrder=2, TimeFromOrigin=115`. If you're relying on "the order the data was inserted" to keep these rows in sequence then you'll have big trouble.

Comment: Why is there no StopOrder value of 7 in the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT [Route], [StopOrder],
           CAST(LEFT([DepartureTime], LEN([DepartureTime])-2) AS int) AS DTH, CAST(RIGHT([DepartureTime],2) AS int) AS DTM,
           CASE WHEN [TimeFromOrigin]<>0 THEN CAST(LEFT([TimeFromOrigin], LEN([TimeFromOrigin])-2) AS int) ELSE 0 END AS TFOH, CAST(RIGHT([TimeFromOrigin],2) AS int) AS TFOM,
           SUM(CASE WHEN [TimeFromOrigin]<>0 THEN CAST(LEFT([TimeFromOrigin], LEN([TimeFromOrigin])-2) AS int) ELSE 0 END*60 + CAST(RIGHT([TimeFromOrigin],2) AS int)) OVER(PARTITION BY [Route] ORDER BY [StopOrder] ROWS 1 PRECEDING)-CASE WHEN [TimeFromOrigin]<>0 THEN CAST(LEFT([TimeFromOrigin], LEN([TimeFromOrigin])-2) AS int)*60+CAST(RIGHT([TimeFromOrigin],2) AS int) ELSE 0 END AS TT
           FROM tbl_all)
SELECT B.[Route], B.[DepartureTime], B.[StopOrder], B.[TimeFromOrigin],
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN FLOOR((TFOH*60+TFOM-TT)/60)=0 THEN NULL ELSE FLOOR((TFOH*60+TFOM-TT)/60) END, CASE WHEN FLOOR((TFOH*60+TFOM-TT)/60)>0 THEN REPLICATE('0',-(LEN((TFOH*60+TFOM-TT) % 60)-2)) ELSE '' END, (TFOH*60+TFOM-TT) % 60) AS [TimeBetween],
       CONCAT(CASE WHEN DTH+TFOH>24 THEN 0+CASE WHEN DTM+TFOM>=60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ELSE DTH+TFOH+CASE WHEN DTM+TFOM>60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END,CASE WHEN DTM+TFOM>=60 THEN DTM+TFOM-60 ELSE DTM+TFOM END, REPLICATE('0',-(LEN(CASE WHEN DTM+TFOM>=60 THEN DTM+TFOM-60 ELSE DTM+TFOM END)-2))) AS [ArrivalTime]
FROM tbl_all AS B LEFT OUTER JOIN A ON B.[Route]=A.[Route] AND B.[StopOrder]=A.[StopOrder]
```

Comment: I'm getting some results with your query, now I just need to understand. btw, are you the God of SQL? :)

Comment: At writing queries I'm pretty good. At the rest not so much.
PS - If it works for you, please place the green check mark to inform future visitors that this solution works.

Comment: I'll do soon. One more thing, instead of 1760, is it possible to have 1800? Please check screenshot http://gyazo.com/a031ce67ab5bd217f52a76cd26643ca8 Thanks @jbarker2160

Comment: It's possible, but it's a lot of code.  You can fix this yourself.  Just take the last two digits and divide by 60 then add them then multiply by 60 then check and see if it's more than 60, etc.  Not difficult, but a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks again, I just marked your answer as a solution. @jbarker2160

Comment: is it simple modification to insert the ArrivalTime in the table field right away instead of selecting and displaying? Thanks

Comment: thanks a million. I don't know if you saw the last comment, is it easy to modify that query to actually insert the value in the arrivaltime field for that row? Thanks again

Comment: You can INSERT by using an INSERT SELECT statement.

Comment: fyi, I'm getting this error with the updated query: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62209/discussion-between-laziale-and-jbarker2160).

Answer (score 1):

Here another example of how you might write it:

```
declare @depart int = 1830
declare @time int = 115
declare @sum time;

with CTE_t
as
(
    select 
        TIMEFROMPARTS(left(@depart,len(@depart)/2),right(@depart,2),01,0,0) as DTime,
        dateadd(minute,@time
                , 
                TIMEFROMPARTS(left(@depart,len(@depart)/2),right(@depart,2),01,0,0)) as mySum
)
select 
    t.DTime as DepTime,
    t.mySum as ArriTime
from CTE_t t
```